# Получение URL адресов из выдачи Google

Tags: python, google-search

Нужно получить URL адреса из выдачи Google средствами Python. Как это можно сделать? Пробовала `BeautifulSoup`, но выдача Google не отображается в исходнике.

Comment: Т.е вы ввели запрос в гугл, и хотите вытащить укрлы результатов?

Comment: Да, именно так.

Comment: Тогда пробуй Selenium. Должно ролучиться

Comment: имеются подробные решения, но на C# https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/609395

Comment: Советую прикладывать код того, как вы пробовали.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не знаю, какая проблема возникла с `BeautifulSoup`, но вот, как мне кажется, рабочее решение, использующее `BeautifulSoup`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

query = 'привет'

r = requests.get('https://www.google.ru/search?q=' + query)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
for element in soup.find_all('h3', class_='r'):
    element = element.contents[0]
    link = element['href']

    # проверяем, что это ссылка на сайт, а не, например, «картинки по вашему запросу»
    prefix = '/url?q='
    if link.startswith(prefix):
        link = link[len(prefix):]
        print(link)
```

Comment: Ого) спасибо большое!

Comment: Не за что) Вот его @youhavenopass благодарите, [это его код](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/673788/227016)